# How to sort the first 20 rows in first column in alphabetical order in a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm new to R coding and i'm doing exercises and I got stuck. In my data frame, the first row are patients e.g patient 1, patient 2 etc and the first column are gene names eg gene abc123,gene def456. What I want to know is how to sort the first 20 rows in column 1 in alphabetical order. Thanks

**EDIT**
I have put up a screenshot of the file in excel and i am trying to extract the ones in the red box in alphabetical order. I am unsure what to call column 1 in the console as it doesn't have a heading. In the file provided, each row represents expression values for a single gene, and each column
 represents expression values for a single sample (patient).

The first column of each row is the gene identifier: (gene-symbol|entrez ID)
 e.g. "A2M|2" (A2M is the gene-symbol and 2 is the entrez database identifier for alpha 2 macroglobulin)

Each sample identifier is formatted as: TCGA-ID_Tissue
where the Tissue is either "TissueA" or "TissueB" e.g. "TCGA-AA-3548_TissueA"

The question is "Sort the gene names alpahabetically (A-Z) and print out the first 20 gene names"

[screenshot of the table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B7tAW.png)

Comment: You can use `sort` to sort characters vectors.

Comment: Have a look at the `order` function in base R or `arrange` in dplyr package

Comment: In this case, you may want `sort(data$col1[1:20])`. If you want to order all the rows, the use `data[order(data$col1), ]`

Comment: @Headpoint sort will not order rows, just the vector

Comment: @TylerRinker, yeah, I may have misunderstood the question since it says `sort the first 20 rows in first column...`

Comment: I accidentally left something out. Meant to also say that it wants the gene names in alphabetical order but i dont know what to call it in the data frame since it doesnt have labels. I've tried naming it 'col1' but that doesn't work. The only method that i've tried that works is df[order(1)] but i cant specifically get just the gene names

Comment: It will help if you include some example data, since the descriptions of it are not very clear.

Comment: I used `col1` to mean name of a column since I do not know the names of the columns you have. So, substitute the name of the column you are interested in for `col1`.

Comment: Dovetailing on @neilfws's comment. It's more likely that we will be able to help you if you provide a [complete minimal reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to go along with your question. Something we can work from and use to show you how it might be possible to answer your question I will also recommend to take a look at the [_how do I ask a good question_](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). It's also generally good to demonstrate you already put some effort into it.

Comment: Thank you guys for the feedback and help. I have uploaded the table of what i'm trying to explain. Sorry If i wasn't clear.